# Remove or prevent the active widget highlight

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

[image: NSOutlineView with blue highlight ring]

In the above example image, how do I go about preventing the blue highlight you can see on the top and right side of the `NSOutlineView` control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called the "Focus Ring". You should be able to stop your view from drawing it either through IB:

[image: Focus Ring popup menu set to "None"]

Or in code, using [`setFocusRingType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCJHACC):

```
[myView setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
```